# Behavior of a function defined by two infinite integrals around the singularity point

Tags: real-analysis, integration, indefinite-integrals, contour-integration, complex-integration

Bounty ending tomorrow:

Consider the following function defined by two infinite integrals:
$$
F(\epsilon) = \int_0^\infty 
 \frac{q^3 (1+q)e^{-2q}}{q^4+\epsilon^4} \, \mathrm{d} q
 +  \int_0^\infty \frac{\, G_q \, e^{-q}}{q^2(q^4+\epsilon^4)} \, \mathrm{d} q 
$$
where
$$
G_q := G \left( \left[ \left[\frac{1}{2} \right] , [\,]\right] , 
  \left[ \left[ \frac{9}{2},\frac{5}{2} \right], \left[\frac{3}{2}\right] \right] ,\frac{q^2}{4}  \right) \, , 
$$
with $G$ being the Meijer G-function.
The goal is to study the behavior of $F$ around the singularity point, i.e. as $\epsilon\to 0$.
Numerically, it can clearly be observed that $F$ scales logarithmically with $\epsilon$. I am wondering whether this behavior can be shown analytically via a rigorous analysis, e.g. using perturbation techniques. Your help or hints are highly appreciated and are most welcome.

Thanks
H

Comment: any idea how $G(q)$ scales as $q\rightarrow 0_+$?

Comment: @tired I think that $G \to 0$ as $q \to 0$, but I can't say something about its evolution (I don't have Maple or Mathematica installed in this PC...)

Comment: mathematica says that $G(q)\sim C q^5$ as $q\rightarrow 0$ so unluckily both integrands seem to give a similar logish contribution as $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$

Comment: can you perform the analysis for the first integral? if yes, does it already explain the leading order behaviour of both integrals?

Comment: @tired Honestly, I don't know how to solve the first integral manually. I will give it a try using the residue theorem. Maybe Mathematica knows how to solve that?

Comment: you well get some exponetial integrals if you go that way... doing asymptotics by for example matched expansions should be simpler

Comment: if i am not mistaken the first integral scales as $\log(\epsilon)-\gamma$

Comment: @tired if you could please elaborate on these two integrals a bit and provide arguments about the scaling behavior as $\epsilon \to 0$, I would be happy to forward the bounty to you. Thanks!

Comment: if i find something for the one with the G-function i will gladly write something up

Comment: it seems that the G-function reduces to combination of Bessels. if this would be true everything would become orders of magnitudes simpler. if i where you, would look what i can find...
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=MeijerG%5B%7B%7B1%2F2%7D,%7B%7D%7D,%7B%7B9%2F5,5%2F2%7D,%7B3%2F2%7D%7D,x%5E2%2F4%5D

Comment: have you suceeded in the reduction i sketched above? if yes, i think i will try to provide the asymptotics (i think i know what to do then)

Comment: The reduction formula is much clearer to prove if we generalize a bit. It turns out that 
$$
G_{2,1}^{1,3}\left(\tfrac{x^2}{4}\left|\begin{smallmatrix}b\\
a,b+2,b+1\end{smallmatrix}\right.\right)
$$

can be reduced to a linear combination of four modified Besselfunctions of the first kind

Comment: furthermore by asymptotic matching, i get that the first integral scales as $1/(2\epsilon)$ which is in good agreement with numerical calculations

Comment: @tired thanks for your comments. Can you post a clear answer for the questions and explain in some mote details your calculation steps? Thanks

Comment: i can only work on this in some of my time after work. there are subtilities to overcome (essentially some very nasty cancellations in the second integral with $G$) which i think now i can handle but this can take a while so please be patient

Comment: and, more important try to solve your question by the help of my hints, this might well be faster then waiting for me. they are pretty solid ... (i give you another one: the sum of four modified Bessel's of the first kind can acutally be rewritten as a sum of two modified Bessel's of the second kind which makes asymptotic matching much, much simpler)

Comment: @tired Thanks for your hints. I am currently out of my office and do not have access to Maple or Mathematica. I will have a deeper look at it next week. ... Btw, the bounty will end in two days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A technique similar to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2675166) will work. The tail at infinity can be neglected, and we have
$$ I_1 = \int_0^\infty \frac {q^3 (1 + q)} {q^4 + \epsilon^4} e^{-2q} dq \sim
\int_0^1 \frac {q^3} {q^4 + \epsilon^4} dq \sim
-\ln \epsilon.$$
The expansion for the G-function at zero is found from the residues:
$$G_q = G_{1,3}^{2,1}\left( \frac {q^2} 4 \middle| 
 {\frac 1 2 \atop \frac 5 2, \frac 9 2, \frac 3 2} \right) \sim\\
-\operatorname{Res}_{y=5/2}
 \frac {\Gamma\left( \frac 1 2 + y \right) \Gamma\left( \frac 5 2 - y \right)
   \Gamma\left( \frac 9 2 - y \right)}
  {\Gamma \left( - \frac 1 2 + y \right)}
 \left( \frac {q^2} 4 \right)^y = \frac {q^5} {16}.$$
Then, in the same way as for $I_1$,
$$I_2 = \int_0^\infty \frac {G_q} {q^2 \left( q^4 + \epsilon^4 \right)}
 e^{-q} dq \sim
\int_0^1 \frac {q^3} {16(q^4 + \epsilon^4)} dq \sim
-\frac {\ln \epsilon} {16},\\
F(\epsilon) = I_1 + I_2 \sim -\frac {17 \ln \epsilon} {16}.$$
To obtain the next term, a regularization can be applied to $I_1$ to get
$$I_1 \sim -\ln \epsilon +
\int_0^1 \left( \frac {q^3 (1 + q)} {q^4 + \epsilon^4} e^{-2q} -
 \frac 1 q \right) \bigg\rvert_{\epsilon=0} dq +
\int_1^\infty \frac {q^3 (1 + q)} {q^4 + \epsilon^4} e^{-2q}
 \bigg\rvert_{\epsilon=0} dq,$$
and, repeating the same procedure for $I_2$, we find
$$F(\epsilon) \sim -\frac {17 \ln \epsilon} {16} -
 \gamma - \ln 2 + \frac 1 2 +\\
 \int_0^1 \left( q^{-6} e^{-q} G_q - \frac 1 {16 q} \right) dq +
 \int_1^\infty q^{-6} e^{-q} G_q dq.$$

Answer (score 1):

Your Integral may be expressed as a Meijer G-Function of two Variables, 
 which is discussed by Agarwal in 1964 for the first time. A more general form is the H-Fox-Function of two Variables 
 which can be found in the standard publication of Mathai: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/266566090_The_H-function_Theory_and_Applications.

```
The first of the two indefinite integrals:
```

$$F_{1}\left( \epsilon \right) =\int_{0}^{\infty }\frac{q^{3}\left( 1+q\right)
\exp \left( -2q\right) }{q^{4}+\epsilon ^{4}}dq$$

can be solved analytically in terms of two Meijer G-functions:

$$F_{1}\left( \sigma \right) \frac{1}{16\sqrt{2}\pi ^{\frac{3}{2}}\sigma ^{3}}%
\left[ G_{1,5}^{5,1}\left( 16\,\sigma ^{4}\left\vert 
\begin{array}{c}
-,-,\frac{3}{4},-,- \\ 
\frac{3}{4},1,\frac{5}{4},\frac{3}{2},\frac{7}{4}%
\end{array}%
\right. \right) +\frac{1}{4\,\sigma }G_{1,5}^{5,1}\left( 16\,\sigma
^{4}\left\vert 
\begin{array}{c}
-,-,1,-,- \\ 
1,1,\frac{5}{4},\frac{3}{2},\frac{7}{4}%
\end{array}%
\right. \right) \right] $$

where we use $\sigma =\frac{\epsilon }{4}$ to have the same notation later
on for the second indefinite integral:

$$F_{2}\left( \epsilon \right) =\int_{0}^{\infty }\frac{1}{q^{2}\left(
q^{4}+\epsilon ^{4}\right) }G_{1,3}^{2,1}\left( \frac{q^{2}}{4}\left\vert 
\begin{array}{c}
-,\frac{1}{2},- \\ 
\frac{9}{2},\frac{5}{2},\frac{3}{2}%
\end{array}%
\right. \right) \exp \left( -q\right) dq$$

The first and the last function can be found in 
[The wolfram functions side](http://functions.wolfram.com/).
They can be expressed in terms of their Meijer G-identities
and then $F_{2}$ can be evaluated using the
integration theorem for Meijer G-functions (http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/MeijerG/21/02/04/)

$$\int_{0}^{\infty }t^{\alpha -1}G_{p,q}^{m,n}\left( \left\vert 
\begin{array}{c}
a_{1},...,a_{p} \\ 
b_{1},...,b_{q}%
\end{array}%
\right. \right) \times $$

$$G_{p_{1},q_{1}}^{m_{1},n_{1}}\left( x\,t\left\vert 
\begin{array}{c}
a_{11},...,a_{1p_{1}} \\ 
b_{11},...,b_{1q_{1}}%
\end{array}%
\right. \right) \times G_{p_{2},q_{2}}^{m_{2},n_{2}}\left( y\,t\left\vert 
\begin{array}{c}
a_{21},...,a_{2p_{2}} \\ 
b_{21},...,b_{2q_{2}}%
\end{array}%
\right. \right) dt$$
$$z^{-\alpha
}G_{p,q,p_{1},q_{1},p_{2},q_{2},}^{m,n,m_{1},n_{1},m_{2},n_{2}}\left( 
\begin{array}{c}
1-\alpha -b_{1},...,1-\alpha -b_{q} \\ 
1-\alpha -a_{1},...,1-\alpha -a_{p}%
\end{array}%
\left\vert 
\begin{array}{c}
a_{11},...,a_{1p_{1}} \\ 
b_{11},...,b_{1q_{1}}%
\end{array}%
\right. \left\vert 
\begin{array}{c}
a_{21},...,a_{2p_{2}} \\ 
b_{21},...,b_{2q_{2}}%
\end{array}%
\right. \left\vert \frac{x}{z},\frac{y}{z}%
\begin{array}{c}
\\ 
\end{array}%
\right. \,\right) $$

The Meijer G-identities corresponding to the functions are:
$$\exp \left( -q\right) =G_{0,1}^{1,0}\left( q\left\vert 
\begin{array}{c}
-,- \\ 
0,-%
\end{array}%
\right. \right) $$
$$\frac{1}{q^{2}\left( q^{4}+\epsilon ^{4}\right) }=\frac{1}{\epsilon ^{6}}%
G_{1,1}^{1,1}\left( \left( \frac{q}{\epsilon }\right) ^{4}\left\vert 
\begin{array}{c}
-\frac{1}{2},- \\ 
-\frac{1}{2},-%
\end{array}%
\right. \right) $$

After some algebraic manipulations and variable transformations, using
(http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/MeijerG/17/02/03/) we
conclude:

$$F_{2}\left( \sigma \right) =\frac{1}{32\sqrt{2}\pi ^{\frac{5}{2}}\sigma ^{6}}\int_{0}^{\infty }t^{\frac{1%
}{4}}G_{1,1}^{1,1}\left( \frac{t}{\sigma ^{4}}\left\vert 
\begin{array}{c}
-\frac{1}{2},- \\ 
-\frac{1}{2},-%
\end{array}%
\right. \right) \times G_{2,6}^{4,2}\left( t\left\vert 
\begin{array}{c}
-,-,\frac{1}{4},\frac{3}{4},-,- \\ 
\frac{9}{4},\frac{11}{4},\frac{5}{4},\frac{7}{4},\frac{3}{4},\frac{5}{4}%
\end{array}%
\right. \right) $$

$$\times G_{0,4}^{4,0}\left( t\left\vert 
\begin{array}{c}
-,-,-,- \\ 
0,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{4},\frac{3}{4}%
\end{array}%
\right. \right) dt =$$

$$= \frac{1}{32\sqrt{2}\pi ^{\frac{5}{2}}\sigma ^{5}}%
~G_{1,1,2,6,0,4}^{1,1,4,2,4,0}\left( 
\begin{array}{c}
\frac{5}{4},- \\ 
\frac{5}{4},-%
\end{array}%
\left\vert 
\begin{array}{c}
-,-,\frac{1}{4},\frac{3}{4},-,- \\ 
\frac{9}{4},\frac{11}{4},\frac{5}{4},\frac{7}{4},\frac{3}{4},\frac{5}{4}%
\end{array}%
\right. \left\vert 
\begin{array}{c}
-,-,-,- \\ 
0,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{4},\frac{3}{4}%
\end{array}%
\right. \left\vert \sigma ^{4},\sigma ^{4}%
\begin{array}{c}
\\ 
\end{array}%
\right. \,\right) $$

A similar example can be found here: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/269504875_Capacity_of_k_-_m_Shadowed_Fading_Channels. 
You may find also the source code for implementing the function in Mathematica in the publication above. Due to the lack of time, I can not check, 
if the solution of your Integral reduces to functions of only one Variable, since  $\frac{x}{z}=\frac{y}{z}=\sigma ^{4}$. You may do this numerical, 
also I can provide the H-Fox-Function of one variable.

Comment: this doesn't answer the question at all :-/

Comment: @tired: Why?. The goal is to study the behavior of F around the singularity point, i.e. as ϵ→0, or for sigma->0. Since some authors see. (Mathai)  derive general expressions for series expansions, derivatives and special cases for reduction of the H-Fox-Function of 2 variables the desired information can be obtained. We have only do some more work  on it!

Comment: the problem is to find this expansion in small $\epsilon$. i don't see any progress in this direction...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will check the correctness of these results numerically. I think that the behavior near the singular point should follow forthwith via asymptotic analysis when $\sigma \to 0$

Comment: In the standard publication of Mathai: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/266566090_The_H-function_Theory_and_Applications. in 1.7 Asymptotic Expansions you find some Expansion theorems for the H-Fox-Function of one variable and in International Journal of Innovative Research in Science,
Engineering and Technology
(An ISO 3297: 2007 Certified Organization)
Vol. 2, Issue 9, September 2013
Copyright to IJIRSET www.ijirset.com 4914
A Study of H -Function of Two Variables
Yashwant Singh1 Harmendra Kumar Mandia

Comment: Thank you for the bounty, I got another idea to get a more clear view of the asymptotic analysis. In fact transforming from $(t^4+\epsilon^4)^alpha$ to $Log[t+epsilon]$ (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2565726/integrating-int-0-frac-pi2-x-log-tan-x2n1-dx) and series expansion of the $exp-function$ could lead in the right direction, coming up with a $log(epsilon)$-term and an H-Fox-function.